# How to return to secondary function?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

i already create some retrofit function like this code

```
    class CallBack<T>(val context: Context) : Callback<T> {
        lateinit var response: ((Response<T>) -> Unit)

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<T>, response: Response<T>) {
            if (!response.isSuccessful) {
                (context as Activity).window.decorView.rootView.snackBar(Toast.ERROR,
                    context.getString(R.string.error, response.code(), response.message()), R.drawable.ic_error)
            } else {
                this.response.invoke(response)
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<T>, t: Throwable) {
            (context as Activity).window.decorView.rootView.snackBar(Toast.ERROR,
                context.getString(R.string.cannotConnect), R.drawable.ic_error)
        }
    }

    fun <T> Call<T>?.queue(context: Context, callback: CallBack<T>.() -> Unit) {
        val callBack = CallBack<T>(context)
        callback.invoke(callBack)
        this?.enqueue(callBack)
    }
```

but everytime i used it, i need to write something like this

```
    api().getNotification(token, user.id).queue(requireContext()){
            response = {
             //command
            }
        }
```

how to make function that i dont have to rewrite response = {}
sorry for bad english btw.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is correct except one thing, you can directly assign your response lambda receiver while creating `CallBack`class rather than explicitly assigning it on consumer side.

Check out refactored code below:

```
class CallBack<T>(
    val context: Context,
    private val response: (Response<T>.() -> Unit) // Accept argument by reference
) : Callback<T> {

    override fun onResponse(call: Call<T>, response: Response<T>) {
        if (!response.isSuccessful) {
            (context as Activity).window.decorView.rootView.snackBar(
                  Toast.ERROR,
                  context.getString(R.string.error, response.code(), response.message()), 
                  R.drawable.ic_error
            )
        } else {
            this.response.invoke(response)
        }
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<T>, t: Throwable) {
          (context as Activity).window.decorView.rootView.snackBar(
                 Toast.ERROR,
                 context.getString(R.string.cannotConnect), 
                 R.drawable.ic_error
          )
    }
}

fun <T> Call<T>?.queue(context: Context, response: Response<T>.() -> Unit) {
    val callBack = CallBack(context, response) // Pass your response callback here directly
    this?.enqueue(callBack)
}
```

And then you can use it like below:

```
api().getNotification(token, user.id).queue(requireContext()) {
    // `this` will be your response here
}
```